# embercli bootstrap for ember and modal dialog

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, broccolijs

Anyone using bootstrap-for-ember with embercli ?

I keep getting :

> 'BootStrap' is not defined.

On a line that reads:

```
return BootStrap.ModalManager.show('myModal');
```

Ive got the modal defined in the template and have bootstrap for ember installed via bower and included in my brocfile.js as follows:

```
app.import('vendor/ember-addons.bs_for_ember/dist/js/bs-core.min.js');
app.import('vendor/ember-addons.bs_for_ember/dist/js/bs-modal.min.js');
```

I have read other posts (guy was using grunt tho) about ensuring that bs-core is the first loaded...
Tried :

```
app.import('vendor/ember-addons.bs_for_ember/dist/js/bs-core.min.js');
app.import('vendor/ember-addons.bs_for_ember/dist/js/!(bs-core).min.js');
```

But it didn't make a difference, still getting the error...

Full code in controller is as follows:

```
 var ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
        actions:{
            showUser: function(theUser){
                return BootStrap.ModalManager.show('myModal');
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to take this the wrong way, but you really should be trying to debug more yourself. That error is as plain as day. `BootStrap` is not defined. A quick look at the source code will tell you why:

```
Bootstrap = window.Bootstrap = Ember.Namespace.create()
```

Change `BootStrap` to `Bootstrap` and you won't have that issue any more.

Comment: Oh crumbs... I'm in the middle of tryin to learn this stuff so its hard to know sometimes if the problem is one thing or another... I did a copy and paste of that code from an example, so just assumed the call was right...
Thanks for letting me down gently.